# Rendering Markdown in Nunjucks gives block tag error

Tags: node.js, express, markdown, nunjucks

I am trying to render Markdown in a file using Nunjucks markdown, but I am getting a block tag error when I try to render the file.

I am sure I am not registering the block tag, but I am not sure how to do it, since I am new to rendering in express and Nunjucks.

```
// index.js
const nunjucks = require("nunjucks");
const markdown = require('nunjucks-markdown');
const marked = require('marked');

exports.testmarkdown = async (req, res) => {
  var env = nunjucks.configure('views');
  markdown.register(env, marked);
  res.render("testmarkdown");
};

// template
{% markdown %}
# Hello World
{% endmarkdown %}

//error message
Template render error: (/Users/meow/sa-blog/views/testmarkdown.html) [Line 2, Column 4]
  unknown block tag: markdown
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you extend `environment` with markdown but use `nunjucks` to render.
If you want to add customization to `nunjucks` then you should use `environment`.

```
const express = require('express');
const nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
const markdown = require('nunjucks-markdown');
const marked = require('marked');
const app = express();

var env = new nunjucks.Environment(
    new nunjucks.FileSystemLoader('./views'), {
    autoescape: true
});

env.express(app);
markdown.register(env, marked);
app.set('views','./views');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.html');
});

app.listen (3000, () => console.log('Listening on port 3000'));
```

Comment: terrific answer, thank you! I guess i am still a little confused why the markdown is registering the env, vs the env registering the markdown. :/

Comment: The API-call `env.addExtension('MyExtension', new MyExtension());` is used to extend environment. So `markdown.register(env, marked);` is a weird to me too.

Comment: thanks, glad to know i am not alone in thinking it is weird. node api naming is so inconsisten